# Using Xpath to select text with multiple empty sibling tags

Tags: jquery, html, xpath, cheerio

I'm trying to write an xpath that will grab the inner text values of the following  tags, ideally I'd like to use an OR statment so that I can have one xpath select the text: **Pay** or **Paid** in both cases.

case 1

```html
<td>
<a class="btn btn-success">Pay</a>
<div class="display:none"></div>
<div class="display:none"></div>
<div class="display:none"></div>
<div class="display:none"></div>
<div class="display:none"></div>
</td>
```

case 2

```html
<td>
<div class="display:none"></div>
<div class="display:none"></div>
<div class="display:none"></div>
<div class="display:none"></div>
Paid
<div class="display:none"></div>
</td>
```

The approach I'm trying to take right now is to first try and just have the xpath ignore all the `<div class="display:none"></div>` because the xpath
`//td/text()` just ends up pickup up all of the empty div tags.

I've trying out these approaches to try and avoid the empty  tags:

```
//td::child[@text='Pay' OR @text='Paid']
//td/text()
//td::child[not(@class="display:none")]
```

These xpaths are eventually getting used to extract data with cheerio.js another approach I haven't looked into yet would be do try and iterate over the results from `//td/text()`

Has anyone faced this kind of problem before?

Comment: It's not clear if you want to select some node (element or text node) or just to get some string value.

Comment: to clarify I need to specifically get the text node. I'm using cheerio.js to parse the html and extract a text value, not a html tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all text-nodes which having any content after normalize-space:

`//text()[boolean(string-length(normalize-space(.)))]`

upd: my decision is overextended. See comment by @Alejandro

Comment: That expression is verbose. You just need `//text()[normalize-space()]` to select all not whitespace only text nodes of the document.

Comment: That works for the text node nested under the <a> tag but doesn't grab the 'Paid' string in the 1st case. When I changed it to ```//text()[boolean(string-length(normalize-space(.)))]``` it worked for both cases.  @Alejandro ```//text()[normalize-space()]``` works flawlessly as well!